# mysql (innodb) increment a value to create a hole

Tags: mysql

say I have a simple tree type table

```
id(key)     | parent | order
============================
1           | 0      | 0
2           | 0      | 1
4           | 2      | 0
5           | 2      | 1
6           | 2      | 2
```

I want to insert a new node so that it has `parent = 2` and `order = 1`, so it then the table data looks like:

```
id(key)     | parent | order
============================
1           | 0      | 0
2           | 0      | 1
4           | 2      | 0
5           | 2      | 2
6           | 2      | 3
7           | 2      | 1
```

E.g. existing rows increment their order value.

What's the best way to ensure that existing rows increment their order (non-key field) starting at an existing arbitrary value, to make a hole for my insert statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a new row with parent `$p` and order position `$o` you can:

```
UPDATE table SET order = order + 1 WHERE parent = $p AND order >= $o
```

and then:

```
INSERT INTO order (id,parent,order) VALUES($id,$p,$o)
```